# Context pointing to external directory in Jetty 9

Tags: deployment, jetty

I want to deploy a .war file to Jetty by setting up a context that points to my external .war (outside webapps folder). I know how to do this in Tomcat, but I can't figure out how to do this for Jetty 9.

In Tomcat I placed an .xml file to configure my context in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost :

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <!--  Context fragment for deploying ServletExample.war  -->
  <Context path="/CurrencyServlet" docBase="/Users/macbook/Desktop/School/Java/Temp/CurrencyServlet.war" debug="0" privileged="true"/>
```

Can anyone provide a simple example for Jetty 9?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the provided $jetty_home/webapps/test.xml file. In jetty9 you can configure your webapps, etc. by placing a ContextProvider config file in $jetty_home/webapps.

Have a look at the docs: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-contexts.html

This is how you configure the path to your webapp:

```
<Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/test</Set>
```